# Syntax highlighting on iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, syntax, syntax-highlighting

Is there fast and simple way to highlight text on iOS 6? I need to create an Objective-C editor on iOS 6 and I think that NSAttributedString is enough. 
I think that I need the definition of Objective-C syntax, but how to use it? Could anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Hints: NSMutableAttributedString, NSMakeRange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an Objective-C lexer, which will transform your raw code into a tree of tokens representing the logicals parts of the language.

You can then take these tokens, color them and re-build the text data from it.

The obvious lexer solution would be to use either GCC's frontend or Clang, but it doubt they are available for iOS, or that Apple let you run these.

I used [Pygments](http://pygments.org/docs/lexers/) for a related project (not on iOS though), but its results are quite poor in my opinion, and I don't know if calling Python libs is possible on iOS (it is on OS X).

Due to iOS limitation, I'd say it would be simpler to do the syntax highlighting on a server, and send the result back to iOS.

**EDIT**:

Here is a link to the [complete (?) Objective-C 2.0 grammar](https://github.com/iamdc/Objective-C-Grammar/blob/master/ObjC.Grm). I don't think you want to write your own parser.

Searching for the grammar I stumbled upon [ParseKit](https://github.com/iamdc/Objective-C-Grammar/blob/master/ObjC.Grm), which seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: The server solution would be a good option, but I need Internet connection to do this.  
Furthermore, anyone know where I can  find Objective-C syntax definition?

Thanks!