# How to display .m file content in objective c programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitextview

I need to display the content of a .h/.m file on the iPhone's screen, maybe in a UITextView, how can I do that ?
The problem is that i need the code to be coloured exactly as shown in code.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Add script as text/string resource, and display it in syntax highlighter… or in a web view with syntax highlighting jslibrary.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16971366/syntax-highlighting-on-ios-6/16971896#16971896).

The best solution seems to be [ParseKit](https://github.com/iamdc/Objective-C-Grammar/blob/master/ObjC.Grm).